# NHibernate how to get members who have a birthday in following n days

Tags: c#, nhibernate, date

I have a nullable DateTime field named Birthdate for my member table. I need to get members who have a birthday in the next n days. I tried a few methods but none of them worked.

**1**

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(n);

GetAll().Where(
    x => x.BirthDate != null 
    && new DateTime(startDate.Year, x.BirthDate.Value.Month, x.BirthDate.Value.Day, 1, 1, 1) >= startDate 
    && new DateTime(endDate.Year, x.BirthDate.Value.Month, x.BirthDate.Value.Day, 1, 1, 1) <= endDate 
    );
```

can not pass x.BirthDate to DateTime constructor

**2**

```
GetAll().OrderByDescending(m => m.CreateDate)
    .Where(x => x.BirthDate.HasValue 
        && (endDate - x.BirthDate.Value).Days <= n)
```

throws recognition error.

Do you know any working and simple way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried peeking first what `GetAll()` returns before you start filtering it?

Answer (score 0):

[linq-to-nhibernate](/questions/tagged/linq-to-nhibernate) supports a bunch of properties on `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset`. You can see the list [here](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Linq/Functions/DateTimePropertiesHqlGenerator.cs#L16). The [reference documentation](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/index.html) will someday have a dedicated Linq section too. (Already committed, not yet released.)

So, guessing your `GetAll` yields an `IQueryable`, you can write your query that way:

```
var startDate = DateTime.Now;
var endDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(n);
if (startDate.Year == endDate.Year)
{
    // Simple case, just compare months and days.
    GetAll().Where(
        x => x.BirthDate.Value.Month >= startDate.Month &&
            x.BirthDate.Value.Day >= startDate.Day &&
            x.BirthDate.Value.Month <= endDate.Month &&
            x.BirthDate.Value.Day <= endDate.Day);
}
else
{
    // Range spanning two distinct years, so matching dates
    // are either lower months and days than endDate, OR
    // greater months and days than startDate. (Cannot have both.)
    GetAll().Where(
        x => x.BirthDate.Value.Month >= startDate.Month &&
            x.BirthDate.Value.Day >= startDate.Day ||
            x.BirthDate.Value.Month <= endDate.Month &&
            x.BirthDate.Value.Day <= endDate.Day);

}
```

I have removed the check on `HasValue`: if the query is translated to SQL, SQL does not need it in this case.

It should work with [queryover](/questions/tagged/queryover) too by the way, I believe it supports the same `DateTime` properties.